# How to trigger alarm clock on a particular date in android

Tags: android

I want to trigger alarm clock on a date given by me. I have checked a lot but I didn't find anything on how to trigger alarm clock on a specific date. Can anyone tell me how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use AlarmManager class provided in Android API to trigger Alarm on a particular date and time.

There are may sample availble on Internet.Below given are few amongst them.Use their code in your project.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html

http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/

http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-alarm-manager_31.html

You can ask if you have any further queries.Happy coding :)